# Why thwos this ERR: Unknown authentication strategy "loca"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

When I using **passprot.js** it throws this Error *Unknown authentication strategy "local"* !

**config/configuration.js**

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
  var User = require('../model/students');

passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: email }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

**index.js**

```
router.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('test');
});

router.post('/test',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/test',
                                   failureFlash: true })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `local` from the passport middleware.

Example:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: email }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Hope this will solve the issue.